# Core Data executeFetchRequest slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

As the title states, executeFetchRequest on Core Data is slow "some times", and it can even block the UI.

I have a suspicion it is because another thread is saving stuff into Core Data, which prevents me from executing the fetch.

I can't save data in a background thread and execute the fetch, since I would have a chance getting outdated data right?

How would I resolve this?

Comment: If you execute your requests on the main thread, there is a possibility that the UI may be blocked. Coupd you show some of your code?

Comment: If "another thread is saving stuff into Core Data", how can you say "I can't save data in a background thread and execute the fetch" ? Are you using multiple threads or no? How big is the fetch you're doing?

Answer (score 1):

This page is a wonderful explanation of how to improve the design of your core data stack.
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Essentially, the gist of it is that you have a background context (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType) that interacts with your persistent store coordinator. This means that all of the expensive disk writing operations will take place in the background leaving your main thread unblocked. You then have your main NSManagedObjectContext that handles most of the core data interactions. Lastly, whenever you are importing lots of new records or doing a lot of processing, you can create a child context and set its parent to be the main context. That way, you save the child and the changes are pushed up to the main context and then later on, the main context saves automatically and then the background context writes the changes to disk.

Personally, I feel like this is an extremely elegant solution and I adopted it in one of my apps and it has been working exceptionally well.